# Beautiful Soup - urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to download a GIF file with `urrlib`, but it is throwing this error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

This does not happen when I download from other blog sites. This is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request

url_1 = 'https://goodlogo.com/images/logos/small/nike_classic_logo_2355.gif'

source_code = requests.get(url_1,headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})    

path = 'C:/Users/roysu/Desktop/src_code/Python_projects/python/web_scrap/myPath/'

full_name = path + ".gif"    
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_1,full_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `urllib.request.urlretrieve`. Instead, use the `requests` library like this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://goodlogo.com/images/logos/small/nike_classic_logo_2355.gif'

path = "D:\\Test.gif"

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

file = open(path, "wb")

file.write(response.content)

file.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
The remote server is apparently checking the user agent header and rejecting requests from Python's urllib.
`urllib.request.urlretrieve()` doesn't allow you to change the HTTP headers, however, you can use 
`urllib.request.URLopener.retrieve()`:

```
import urllib.request

url_1='https://goodlogo.com/images/logos/small/nike_classic_logo_2355.gif'

path='/home/piyushsambhi/Downloads/'

full_name= path + "testimg.gif"

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
filename, headers = opener.retrieve(url_1, full_name)

print(filename)
```

**NOTE:** You are using Python 3 and these functions are now considered part of the "[Legacy interface](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface)", and `URLopener` has been deprecated. For that reason you should not use them in new code.

Your code imports `requests`, but you don't use it - you should though because it is much easier than `urllib`. Below mentioned code snippet works for me:

```
import requests

url = 'https://goodlogo.com/images/logos/small/nike_classic_logo_2355.gif'
path='/home/piyushsambhi/Downloads/'
full_name= path + "testimg1.gif"

r = requests.get(url)
with open(full_name, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(r.content)
```

**NOTE: CHANGE THE PATH VARIABLE ACCORDING TO YOUR MACHINE AND ENVIRONMENT**